# How do you stop people from going to a page that should be used as log in page?

Tags: php, session, authentication

I am new to php. I am trying to allow users to log in a website. Here are the steps: the php script checks if the $_POST['submit'] is set, if it is set it check if the user input match data in the database, if inputs are correct it redirects users to a log in page. I am trying to stop users from accessing the page that the php script redirect them when their input are correct but I can't. I already try the empty and the isset function but they don't work. How does facebook manage to have users log in without redirecting them to other pages. When you log in facebook the url is http://facebook.com. Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 2):

Upon successful login:

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
```

At the top of every page:

```
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['logged_in'])
{
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();
}
```

At the top of your login page:

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'])
{
    header('Location: other_page_here.php');
    die();
}
```

More on sessions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).