# PHP Login to Members Area

Tags: php, mysql, html

I already have the register page done, and it works smoothly.

Now I need to figure out login part. I want to have it so once the User logs in it brings them to the private page, only signed in users can see. **it doesn't need to be individualization per users, just a basic generic members page.**

(here is the test log in page: http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/member_test/register/login.php )

The code I have now logs them in but only prompts with an echo "Welcome, *username* "

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['form'])){
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$_POST[username]'")) > 0){
    $user_info = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$_POST[username]' LIMIT 1"));

    if($_POST['password'] != $user_info->password){
        echo '<b>Username/Password Invaild</b>';
    }else{
        echo '<b>Welcome, '.$user_info->username.'.</b>';
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_info->id;
    }
}else{
    echo '<b>Username Invalid</b>';

}
}
?>
```

So how do I make it go to a members page?

By the way I am a TOTAL noob at this!

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611858/how-do-you-stop-people-from-going-to-a-page-that-should-be-used-as-log-in-page/9611899#9611899) will help.

In a nutshell, each page checks a session variable to ensure the user is logged in.  If not, they are redirected to the login page.  The reverse is true on the login page.  Once they are successfully logged in, they are redirected to a different page.

Comment: I looked at your example, but can't get it to work.  I must be entering the code snippets into the wrong spots or something...

Comment: where do I enter the "  $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;  "? Do I put that where my echo command is?

Comment: The logged_in variable is set when your user successfully logs in.  You check that variable at the top of every other page.  If it's not true (ie - they haven't logged in yet), you redirect them to your login page.

Comment: Yeah i copied the 2 sets of code, 1 for the login and 1 for the member page.  I just don't know where to paste that $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

Comment: That goes in your code after you've verified the user's credentials and before you redirect them away from your login page.

Comment: Nevermind! it was working the whole time, I was just logged in already so it kept sending me to the member page! haha

Comment: Make sure you include the part where you check if the user is already logged in and trying to access the login page.  You'll want to redirect them back to your members area as they won't need to log in again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8655/discussion-between-dan-graves-and-senoramor)

Answer (score 2):

Here is are links to the PHP Manual which will reiterate the answers previously given and then some.

- [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)
- [http_redirect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php)

Answer (score 1):

Add `header("Location: http://www.example.com/")` at the bottom of your code where the www.example.com is the URL to your private page. You will be redirected to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
header('Location: my_member_page.php');
```

It will redirect the user to the page...

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Location: members.php");
exit;
```

This will forward to "members.php" page.

Comment: So do I replace my "echo" code with this? Will that members.php page need some coding at the top to verify is the user is a valid and signed in?

Comment: Yes replace your "Welcome" echo with the header to divert to the members page.
On the members page you can check the session was started / is still valid and display their username some where to show they are still logged in, or you could pass a variable in your session to indicate they just logged in. If that variable is set you could display a "Thanks for logging in" message if you wanted.